# Sorting only odd/even numbers in assembly, how to copy an array without using already allocated memory?

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, nasm

TL;DR: How to copy elements from one array to another (not all but some)?

I want to perform a sorting algorithm on some array, but so that I only sort odd or even numbers in it, depending on a flag. So my idea was to set a flag on either `0` or `1` and then I'd extract all the numbers that have to be sorted into another array and put `-1` (as a marker) on the positions where those numbers were. After that I'd just insert the sorted numbers back into the original array, for example:

arr1: `5 8 2 4 13 9 14 10 9`

arr2: `8 2 4 14 10`

arr2 (sorted): `2 4 8 10 14`

arr1 (without even numbers): `5 -1 -1 -1 13 9 -1 -1 9`

arr1 (final): `5 2 4 8 13 9 10 14 9`

Now while writing this in a higher language is rather trivial for me, doing it in assembly which I'm learning for a class isn't. The part where I sort the numbers works just fine, but the part that causes me problems is the one where I have to copy the numbers into another array. My main method looks like this:

```
section .data
    arr dd 6,8,1,7,4,2,9,107,10,8,12,16,14,5
    len equ ($-arr) / 4 - 1
section .bss
section .text
extern sort
global _start
_start:
    mov r8, len
    mov esi, arr ; esi points to the start of the array/top of it
    call sort
mov rax, 60
mov rdi, 0
syscall
```

And the subroutine which will do the job (showing only the problematic part):

```
 mov r9d, esi

    .export:
        mov eax, [r9d]
        cdq 
        div dword [divider]
        cmp edx, [flag]
        je .add
        .continue:
            add r9d, 4 ; point to the next number
            inc dword [i]
            cmp r8d, [i]
            jg .export

.add:
    mov edi, [r9d]
    mov dword [r9d], -1 ; put the number in the old array to -1
    sub edi, 4
    inc dword [lenNewArray] ; inc the total number of elements in new array
    jmp .continue
```

Anyway what I want to accomplish is that I add an element that matches the condition to some location and then point `rdi` to that location, when I want to add another element I subtract `-4` from `rdi` so it points to the lower location and put that element there, in the end I'd have `rdi` pointing to the last element which was extracted, is that possible to be done, and is it a bad way?

Comment: It's unclear why you subtract `4`. `edi` is not even a pointer, it's the number you are copying. And you are not even copying it at all, you don't write it out into the new array. PS: every time you use `div` to divide by two a kitten dies. You just want `test eax, 1`. Setting the items to -1 doesn't seem like an optimization, you'd have to compare when writing back anyway, so you might as well just re-test for even.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CCmTNim3 I tried doing this isolated example, but I get a segmentation fault when I run the code.

Comment: You don't even **have** a target array to copy to! How did you expect that code to work?

Comment: So I basically have to have another array as the target, thanks!

Comment: Yes, computer memory exists in fixed size amount, and as this is x86-64 target platform, you have only limited amount of memory available for user process, given by OS. The reserved memory in `.data` section is based on the definitions you write there (you can use also `.bss` section for uninitialized memory, and just reserve some fixed space there). If you didn't define target array, you don't have that memory available, simple as that. (you can dynamically call OS service to give you more memory, but for simple examples like this it's too complex, just allocate fixed size buffer in `.data`).

Comment: It seems to me it would be easier and more efficient to filter the array in-place before sorting.  Search read-only for the first element you want to get rid of (or the end of the array).  Then keep a src pointer and dst pointer, load and src++, test, and conditionally store and dst++.  When you're done, `dst` is pointing to one-past-the-end of the part of the array you want to keep.  Or if you want to filter into a new array, the same algo works with `dst` pointing to the new array.